# c# Automate through a website with user credential posting back checks

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, automation

I am currently looking into changing the way one of our widgets works as it just isn't scalable the way it is.

I'll give you a bit of background and then try to explain how I am trying to improve it:

I have a widget which allows a user to enter there username and password and on submit the information is sent over to MSMQ and sent to my application which works with CEFSharp (i was using WatIN but CEFSharo is chrome based so i came across fewer problems) the application receives the information and automates through the retailers site adding the item to the user basket and then logging out. The user will know whether the product has been placed in the check box successfully by a series of ticks on the website (widget) again sent back from MSMQ.

The problems I am facing are as follows:

If 10 (or more!) users are adding a product to the basket at the same time i need 10 application open to do the automation otherwise the tenth user could be waiting a long time for their succesful add to basket to complete.
MSMQ relies on a Domain controller to send and receive the information.
The automation itself takes a long time.
The current solution is likely to be overcomplicated.

So i was wondering if anyone had any suggestions or could post some links into a simpler more scalable way of achieving what i need which is as follows:

Information submitted by user:

```
1.  Retailer
2.  Username
3.  Password
4.  Product deeplink
5.  Quantity
```

Automation Steps

```
a)  Go to site login page
b)  Enter username
c)  Enter password
d)  Click submit
e)  Check successful (User sees Secure sign in check box ticked)
f)  Go to product page (using deeplink)
g)  Check successful (User sees Locating this product checkbox checked)
h)  Select quantity
i)  Add to basket
j)  Check if successful (User sees Add product to basket checkbox checked)
k)  Log out
l)  Check successful (User sees Log out and forget details successful)
```

**Edit**

Just to make this a little clearer (i think) what i really want to remove is the MSMQ part of the code which currently does the following:

On a seperate server (in my case theDomain controller) MSMQ Receives a message with the following information and sends it over to another server:

```
 Retailer User page login
 Users Username
 User Password
 Product URL
 Quantity user want to add
```

On the other server MSMQ is listening for messages and on receiving the message starts the automation. At certtain points in the automation a Message is created saying whether the user has been successful or not which is sent back to the Domain controller and seen by the user as a tick or cross.

I hope that makes sense!

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated as i am pretty stuck on where to go with this.

Comment: Is there not a way to use an API instead of scraping your way into the retailer's site?

Comment: Your msmq task is effectively an async process but you appear to trying to use it in a synchronous manner. You could remove it & replace the thing the processes the message with a wcf service. You could call this directly from your app.

Comment: @SimonHalsey  i will definetly look into that as an option thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, WCF can still use MSMQ, so if this was important, the message could still travel through MSMQ. The bonus would be your app would no longer be dependant on MSMQ. Look into WCF durable messaging